# Dynamic variables with tkinter entry boxes

Tags: python, variables, inheritance, tkinter

and thanks for reading this. I am currently in the process of converting an Autohokey script into a full fledged Python application. This application will help me automate service requests at work. I currently am having problems understanding how to set a tkinter entry box to a variable that updates dynamically. I am sure there are a million things wrong with this code so try and go easy on me! This is what I have so far:

```
from tkinter import *
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter.ttk import *
import os
import subprocess as sp
import pyautogui
import pyperclip


class SRHelper:
    def __init__(self, master, *args):
        self.master = master
        self.CustID = tk.StringVar()

        self.custLabel = tk.Label(self.master, text="Cust #")
        self.custLabel.grid(row=0, column=0, sticky=W)

        self.custEnt = tk.Entry(self.master, width=10, textvariable=self.CustID)
        self.custEnt.grid(row=0, column=1, sticky=N)

        self.artLabel = tk.Label(self.master, text="Articel ID")
        self.artLabel.grid(row=0, column=2, sticky=N)

        self.artEnt = tk.Entry(self.master, width=12)
        self.artEnt.grid(row=0, column=3, sticky=W)

        self.srLabel = tk.Label(self.master, text="SR #")
        self.srLabel.grid(row=2, column=0, sticky=W, padx=10)

        self.srEnt = tk.Entry(self.master, width=10)
        self.srEnt.grid(row=2, column=1, sticky=N)

        self.aButton = tk.Button(self.master, text="Articles", width=20, command=self.articles_window)
        self.aButton.grid(row=2, column=2, columnspan=2, sticky=W)

        self.sButton = tk.Button(self.master, text="Start", width=12, height=1)
        self.sButton.grid(row=3, column=0, columnspan=2, sticky=W, padx=10)
        self.sButton.bind("<Button-1>", self.start_button)

        self.dButton = tk.Button(self.master, text="Done", width=12, height=1)
        self.dButton.grid(row=4, column=0,columnspan=2, sticky=W, padx=10)

        self.bfButton = tk.Button(self.master, text="Filler", width=12, height=1)
        self.bfButton.grid(row=5, column=0, columnspan=2, sticky=W, padx=10)

        self.taskButton = tk.Button(self.master, text="Task", width=20, height=1)
        self.taskButton.grid(row=6, column=2, columnspan=2, sticky=W)

        self.userEntry = tk.Entry(self.master, width=12)
        self.userEntry.insert(0, "Ctrl+Alt+U")
        self.userEntry.config(state='readonly')

        self.quickEntry = tk.Entry(self.master, width=12)
        self.quickEntry.insert(0, "Ctrl+Alt+Q")
        self.quickEntry.config(state='readonly')

        self.userEntry.grid(row=7, column=2, columnspan=1, sticky=N, pady=5)

        self.quickEntry.grid(row=7, column=3, columnspan=1, sticky=W, pady=5)
        #--------- ListBox --------------
        self.listbox1 = tk.Listbox(self.master)
        self.listbox1.config(width=0, height=6)

        for file in os.listdir("Scripts"):
                self.listbox1.insert(END, file)

        self.listbox1.bind("<Double-Button-1>", double_click)
        self.listbox1.bind('<<ListboxSelect>>', single_click)
        self.listbox1.grid(row=3, column=2, rowspan= 3, columnspan=2, sticky=W)
    def articles_window(self):
        self.newWindow = tk.Toplevel(self.master)
        self.app = Articles(self.newWindow)
    def start_button(self, *args):
         pyautogui.click(219, 174, button='left', clicks=2)
         pyautogui.hotkey('ctrl', 'c')  # Send, ^c
         self.CustID = pyperclip.paste()
         print(self.CustID)

def double_click(event):
    widget2 = event.widget
    selection = widget2.curselection()
#   print(selection)
    value2 = widget2.get(selection[0])
#   print(value)
    location = "C:\\SOMELOCATION\\Scripts\\"
    openfile = location + value2
#   print(openfile)
    fullcmd = "notepad " + openfile
    sp.Popen(fullcmd, shell=False)

def single_click(event):
    widget1 = event.widget
    selection = widget1.curselection()
#   print(selection)
    value1 = widget1.get(selection[0])
#   print(value1)

class Articles:
    def __init__(self, master):
        self.master = master
        self.titleLabel = tk.Label(self.master, text="Title", width=12, height=1)
        self.titleLabel.grid(row=0, column=0, sticky=W)
        self.titleEntry = tk.Entry(self.master, width=40)
        self.titleEntry.grid(row=0, column=1, sticky=W)
        self.titleLabel = tk.Label(self.master, text="Article #", width=12, height=1)
        self.titleLabel.grid(row=0, column=2, sticky=W)
        self.artEntry = tk.Entry(self.master, width=15)
        self.artEntry.grid(row=0, column=3, columnspan=2, sticky=W)
        self.saveButton = tk.Button(self.master, text="Save", width=12, height=1)
        self.saveButton.grid(row=0, column=5, sticky=W)
        self.searchLabel = tk.Label(self.master, text="Search", width=12, height=1)
        self.searchLabel.grid(row=1, column=0, sticky=W)
        self.searchEntry = tk.Entry(self.master, width=40)
        self.searchEntry.grid(row=1, column=1, sticky=W)      
        self.openButton = tk.Button(self.master, text="Open", width=12, height=1)
        self.openButton.grid(row=1, column=4, sticky=W)
        self.clearButton = tk.Button(self.master, text="Clear", width=12, height=1)
        self.clearButton.grid(row=1, column=5, sticky=W)               
        self.tree = ttk.Treeview( self.master, columns=('Title', 'Article #'))
        self.tree['show'] = 'headings'
        self.tree.heading('#0', text='Articles')
        self.tree.heading('#1', text='Title')
        self.tree.heading('#2', text='Article #')
        self.tree.column('#0', stretch=YES)
        self.tree.column('#1', stretch=YES)
        self.tree.column('#2', stretch=YES)
        self.tree.grid(row=3, column=0, columnspan=6, sticky='nsew')
    def close_windows(self):
        self.master.destroy()

def main(): 
    root = tk.Tk()
    app = SRHelper(root)
    root.mainloop()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

The issue is with the start_button function. When the Start button is pressed I want it to move the mouse to a specific spot on the screen, copy what is there into the associated variable, and have that automagically updated into different entry boxes within the main GUI window. I have a feeling the issue is with inheritance between class and methods/functions. I am still learning so any explanation would be greatly appreciated. Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are very close. It's just that tkinter variables are not like python variables. You have to use the `set` method to change the value:

```
self.CustID.set(pyperclip.paste())
```

And the `get()` method to retrieve the value:

```
print(self.CustID.get())
```

Comment: I had a feeling it was something simple, haha. Verified working. Thank you so much Novel!